# Сервер не справляется с запросами контента при загрузке

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Используем фреймворк Vuejs. Проблема заключается в том, что сервер стоит слабый, не справляется с запросами. Загрузка может доходить до 30сек.
Есть ли какие-то способы предзагрузки контента одним запросом? Или сделать очередь загрузки - 1 запрос - загрузка - след запрос.
Ставить сервер мощнее не можем.

Comment: Сервер не справляется с запросами к `API` или сервер не справляется с запросами к отдачи самого контента на `Vue`? И то и то решается на сервере, в первом случае оптимизируется и кэшируется ответ, во втором случае настраивается кэширование статических файлов в `nginx` (`Cache-control`)

Comment: Согласен с @MoloF. Фронт может только снижать количество запросов к серверу. А отдача и скорость отдачи данных(опуская сеть) решается только на стороне сервера.

Comment: Сервер не справляется с запросами. Они приходят, он их обрабатывает, но в какой-то момент встает и ничего не делает  (panding в панели разработчика) . Так вот вопрос в том можно ли предзагружать файлы в порядке очереди или 1 запросом чтобы при загрузке вью он просто вставлял картинки, а не грузил их. В общем, выставить загрузку запрос-загрузка, по порядку